# Google Chrome does not show desktop notification but the sound is working

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, notifications, web-push

I have an application with previously worked well with Google Chrome desktop notifications. But it currently have a strange issue.
When the notification should be worked, I receive the notification sound in browser, but the notification box does not appear anymore!
I've tested this on Firefox and it works without any issue. Also, I tested notification working status at https://pushjs.org/ but it did not work too!
I am using the Chrome version 95.0.4638.54 on Windows 10 64-bit.

May you help me to know what is issue? I did not have it previously.